# TypeScript: how to add a function as a parameter along with prop destructuring with React function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

With React JS I can do this to pass function `handleClick` as a parameter from parent to child component:

Parent:

```
const testData = {
  id: 1,
  title: 'Tesco'
};

const Home = () => {
  
  const handleClick = () => {
    //do something
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Card id={testData.id} title={testData.title}, handleClick={handleClick}
    </>
  )
}
```

Child component:

```
const Card = ({id, title, handleClick}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div key={id}>
        <p>{title}</p>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Now I'm moving to TypeScript, I'm trying to do a similar thing with prop destructuring:

Parent: same as above

Interface:

```
interface IStores {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}
```

Child:

```
interface Props {
  store: IStores
}
const Card = ({ store: {id, title} }: Props, handleClick: object) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div key={id}>
        <p>{title}</p>
        <button onClick={handleClick}></button>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

No error in the child component, but in parent, on line `<Card id={testData.id} title={testData.title}, handleClick={handleClick}`, I got an error at `handleClick`:

```
Type '{ store: IStores; key: number; handleClick: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.
  Property 'handleClick' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.
```

Any idea how to pass `handleClick` to child in this case?

Comment: Your destructuring has curly braces in the wrong spot, you close them too early. They should encapsulate all the props, something like this (untested): `({store: {id, title}: Props, handleClick: () => void})`

Comment: @Jayce444 tried your solution and gave me multiple errors. Are you sure about `store: {id, title}: Props`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typescript error is saying you don't have `handleClick` inside `Props`.

Explanation: You are basically saying, you will get object of type `Props`, which will have `store, handleClick` named key and its respective type of `IStore, function`

So, All you have to do is:

```
interface IStores {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  
}

interface Props {
  store: IStores;
  handleClick: () => void;
}
const Card = ({ store: {id, title}, handleClick }: Props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div key={id}>
        <p>{title}</p>
        <button onClick={handleClick}></button>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For functional components, there's 2 parts to the arguments. There's the actual arguments themselves, then there's the typing of those arguments (separated by a colon). So this should work:

```
interface IStores {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

interface Props {
  store: IStores;
  handleClick: () => void;
}

const Card = ({ store: {id, title} = {} as IStores, handleClick } : Props) => {
  return (
    <div key={id}>
      <p>{title}</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}></button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

So here, `{ store: {id, title} = {} as IStores, handleClick }` is the destructuring of the props, and `Props` is the typing of those destructured props, in this case defined in an interface